# error when using zip function in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.6

I have a very big dataset containing nested list. Here is a small example of my dataset (the structure is exactly like this):

```
[[['id', 'ENS001'], ['name', 'EGSB'], ['Trans', 'TTP']], [['id', 'EN02'], ['name', 'EHGT'], ['Trans', 'GFT']]]
```

I used this code:

```
z = [zip(*i) for i in l]
```

to get something like this:

```
[[('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP')], [('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('EN02', 'EHGT', 'GFT')]]
```

For small dataset like the example it works perfectly, but when I use it for my big dataset it gives many empty lists. I’m using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Consider showing a "big dataset" so people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: actually the structure is like the example but the parent list has 111559 lists inside that. is this what you need?

Comment: @ali can you show where the empty lists in your input are? Is it something like `[['Trans', 'TTP'], [], ['name', 'EHGT']]` or more like `[['Trans', 'TTP'], ['name', 'EHGT']], [], [['Trans', 'GFT'], ['name', 'EGSB']]`

Comment: it is like this : [[['Trans', 'TTP'], ['name', 'EHGT'], []], [['Trans', 'GFT'], ['name', 'EGSB'], []]]

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that you have empty lists in your big dataset, as illustrated by the following example:

```
In [11]: l = [[['id', 'ENS001'], ['name', 'EGSB'], ['Trans', 'TTP']], \
   ....: [['id', 'EN02'], ['name', 'EHGT'], []]]
                                            ↑↑ an empty list here...

In [12]: [zip(*i) for i in l]
Out[12]: [[('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP')], []]
                                                                ↑↑ ...gives an empty
                                                                      list here
```

This happens because `zip` stops when it runs out of elements in the shortest of the iterables.

If you wish to filter empty lists out, this can be done like so:

```
In [15]: [zip(*filter(None, i)) for i in l]
Out[15]: 
[[('id', 'name', 'Trans'), ('ENS001', 'EGSB', 'TTP')],
 [('id', 'name'), ('EN02', 'EHGT')]]
```

Comment: @mehtunguh: It's not hard to generalise this: "many" empty lists in the input can easily cause "many" empty lists in the output.

Comment: @mehtunguh exactly. do you know what to do to remove them

Comment: but it gives only empty lists

Comment: sorry, deleted my comment when trying to edit. I was getting at whether the OP has multiple empty lists within each of the sublists, or multiple empty lists at the top level.